Fate of phosphatidylcholines in exosomes when triglycerides are released from adipocytes
I am not a physiologist by any stretch of the imagination, so excuse me for my potentially naive question.
My understanding is that triglycerides from long-term fat storage are released via exosomes*, whereupon they are split into fatty acids (which are subsequently catabolized during b-oxidation in the mitochondria to generate chemical energy in the form of ATP...). The exosomes are primarily made of phosphatidylcholines. What happens to the phosphatidylcholines (PCs) that form the exosomes? Are the PCs reabsorbed into cell membranes? Or, are they primarily split into their fatty acid constituents, then catabolized by B-oxidation? What is the main fate of the PCs from the exosomes?
*alternatively, are fatty acids primarily released from adipocytes using vesicles instead of exosomes?
Thanks for any insight.
